# Why `autowire=byType` will also inject beans by name?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

I found something not clear about the `autowire=byType` behavior.

Java code under package `my`:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private User user1;
    @Autowired
    private User user2;

    public String getNames() {
        return user1.getName() + " & " + user2.getName();
    }

}
```

Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="user1" class="my.User" autowire="byType">
        <constructor-arg value="Freewind"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="user2" class="my.User" autowire="byType">
        <constructor-arg value="Lily"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Running code:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        UserService service = context.getBean(UserService.class);
        System.out.println(service.getNames());
    }
}
```

It's working well and prints:

```
Freewind & Lily
```

But I was expecting it should not work, because I used `autowire="byType"` when I defined the beans, and there are two beans with the same type `User` in `UserService`.

And, if I changed the name of the bean, say, `user1` -> `user999`, it will report some error like `No qualifying bean of type [my.User] is defined` error.

It seems spring will automatic check the name even if I specified `byType`, which is strange.

PS: I've tested with spring `4.1.3.RELEASE` and `3.2.2.RELEASE`, same behavior.

Comment: You aren't using autowiring by name you are using annotations. The `autowire="byType"` is useless here. `@Autowird` by default is by type, if there are multiple instances found it will try to see if there is a `@Qualifier` too figure out which one to use, if that isn't there it will use the name of the field as final fallback.

Comment: @M.Deinum, your comment perfectly answered my question, thanks. Just want to know where did you find that?

Comment: Which part specifically? But mainly by experience and the urge to want to know how things work (I know large parts of the Spring Framework source code quite well :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I mean the behavior of `@Autowired`. I searched a lot of document, didn't find such explanations

Comment: There is some explanation in the Spring Reference guide and also the javadoc of the class. But indeed not everything is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="user2" class="my.User" autowire="byType">
    <constructor-arg value="Lily"/>
</bean>
```

The `autowire="byType"` here means that you want to have (missing) dependencies injected into this bean `byType`. It only applies to the bean the attribute is placed on. In the xml namespace the default for all the beans could be set.

However in your case you are using actually using annotations (note `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by the usage of `</context:component-scan />`). Annotation driven injection (`@Autowired`, `@Inject` are always by type, `@Resource` uses a name or jndi lookup and as fallback by name).

When starting the application and scanning for components for each needed dependency the [`DependencyDescriptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DependencyDescriptor.html) is created. This class contains the details used for autowiring, it amongst other things contains the type and the name. The name, in case of a `Field` is derived from the actual name.